# NEC 2014: How many 12-2 Romex wires can I run through a hole in ceiling joist?

Tags: wiring

What does the 2014 code say about number of wires run through a bored hole? Can I run 2 Romex 12-2 cables through a 3/4in or 1in hole? I need to add outlets to my unfinished basement (probably 8 total) and I need to run a new circuit from panel. Can I save myself some time and hassle by running my new wire through a current hole w/1 existing wire?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36322/how-many-cables-are-you-allowed-to-run-through-a-single-hole-in-a-wooden-floor-j

Comment: The linked answer nails it and why. complicated math, and what falls out the bottom is four circuits. Unless they're 3-phase, in which case three.  It's the same math as wires-per-conduit.